# APL programming - How can I convert a simple matrix into a picture?

Tags: matrix, bitmap, apl, dyalog

I'm fairly new to APL and I would like to convert a 4x4 binary matrix into an image composed of black and white squares - the sort of thing [found here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html). Documentation says that it's possible using `⎕WC` to create a GUI object and then stating the Bits required? I can't find any examples, though there are some for opening picture files.

Please could someone provide an example using the returned matrix from this APL expression?

```
4 4 ⍴ 1 0 1 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your matrix, `matrix←4 4 ⍴ 1 0 1 0`

Each RGB pixel is encoded as a single integer in base 256: `cb ← matrix × 256 ⊥ 255 255 255`

Now we create the bitmap: `'bm' ⎕WC 'Bitmap' ('CBits' cb)`

And create the content of the corresponding PNG: `png ← bm.MakePNG`

Let's create a native (i.e. non-APL) container file and catch its tie number: `tn ← '\tmp\pic.png' ⎕NCREATE ¯1`

Appending the data: `png ⎕NAPPEND tn`

Untying the file: `⎕NUNTIE tn`

Here's all the code together as a program that takes the filename as left argument and the mask as right argument:

```
∇ filename PNG matrix ; cb ; bm ; png ; tn
  cb ← matrix × 256 ⊥ 255 255 255
  'bm' ⎕WC 'Bitmap' ('CBits'cb)
  png ← bm.MakePNG
  tn ← filename ⎕NCREATE ¯1
  png ⎕NAPPEND tn
  ⎕NUNTIE tn
∇
```

However, you may want to scale the image a bit to actually be able to see it, so let's define a helper function that does the scaling:

```
Scale ← { ⍺ / ⍺ ⌿ ⍵ }
```

Now let's try it:

```
'\tmp\bigpic.png' PNG 100 Scale 3 3 ⍴ 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
]Open \tmp\bigpic.png
```

[image: Windows Photos Screenshot]

Here is a program that instead displays the picture in a separate window:

```
∇ Show matrix ; cb ; bm
  cb ← matrix × 256 ⊥ 255 255 255
  'bm' ⎕WC 'Bitmap' ('CBits'cb)
  'f' ⎕WC 'Form' ('Coord' 'ScaledPixel') ('Size' (⍴ matrix))
  'f.img' ⎕WC 'Image' ('Points' 0 0) ('Picture' bm)
∇
```

So we can do:

```
  Show 100 Scale 3 3 ⍴ 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

[image: Dyalog APL GUI Form Screenshot]

[The full documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/GUI/Objects/Bitmap.htm) for the Bitmap object is available online by entering `]Help Bitmap` or offline by typing `Bitmap` and pressing the F1 key.

Comment: Wow - awesome! Thank you @Adám I appreciate your time and effort. I was going to ask about scaling too but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this is to format the matrix as [netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm):

```
      a←4 4⍴1 0
      img←'P1'(⍕⌽⍴a),⍕¨↓a
      ⍪img
 P1
 4 4
 1 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0
```

write it to a file:

```
      (⊂img)⎕nput'a.pnm'
```

and use [pnm2png](http://www.schaik.com/png/pnmtopng.html) or [an online tool](http://paulcuth.me.uk/netpbm-viewer/) to convert it to a more popular format